# Issue with file upload in java of content-type application/x-compressed

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Below is the code that I have for file upload to s3 cloud server. But file upload is not happening. I am getting no error. Any help experts

```
URL url = new URL(s3Url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-compressed");
connection.setRequestProperty("x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256");
File file = new File("myTar.tar.gz");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
while ((n = fileInputStream.read(buf)) > -1) {
outputStream.write(buf, 0, n);
}
connection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: You should close the OutputStream.  What is the return value of `connection.getResponseCode()`?